# How to use grep to search for regular expressions themselves, without parsing them

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, grep

```
grep . filename.txt
```

This just returns all of the contents in filename.txt, because . is a regular expression that stands for any character. How do I use grep to search for periods, or other regular expressions, like *?

Comment: Have you tried escaping them with \, as in \. or \\*?

Comment: Doesn't work. Dealing with escape characters is something the shell does for you, not the programs themselves. Grep disables most shell preprocessing on the inputs, at least in ubuntu.

Comment: I don't understand why '\.' filename.txt works. It seems to me that wither '.' or \. should work, and I dont see why it works when theyre both used at once. Care to explain?

Comment: @Maksim Your shell treats the contents inside of single-quotes as literals. This means that the `grep` command is actually passed `\.` as the parameter, which it can then interpret as a literal `.`. If you don't have the `\ `, then `grep` simply gets `.` as the parameter, which matches any character. If you don't have the quotes, then your shell will process the `\ `, and again `grep` will simply get `.` as the parameter.

Comment: Ooh, I see. So grep uses \ to denote that something is a literal, but so does the shell. So I need to wrap '\.' in quotes - if I pass in just \., the shell will preprocess away the backslash, and grep just sees ., but if I do '\.', grep sees \. Thanks!

Comment: @Maksim Exactly! This behavior is documented in the manuals for grep and the shell, which is why people were getting a little short from the "lack of research".

Comment: The question, as it is currently stated (and answered), has merit. How to search for a string literal that represents a regular expression is a very valid question. Everyone needs to calm down please.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`grep` uses regular expressions by default, any pattern given to `grep` is assumed to be a regular expression unless you use the `-F` switch.

Expressions such as `*?` are not part of the [POSIX regex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_basic_and_extended) language which is what `grep` uses by default. You can use such constructs by specifying a different regex language, Perl for example:

```
$ cat a.txt
aaaaaaaa
aabbccaaaacccccccccb
bbbbbb
$ grep -oP 'a.*?b' a.txt
aab
aaaacccccccccb
```

To search for a line containing at least one period, use

```
$ grep '\.*' foo.txt
```

For a line containing only periods (or nothing, this will also match an empty line), use

```
$ grep '^\.*$' foo.txt
```

For more complex regexes, use `-F`:

```
$ grep -F '[a-z]*.*[AHG].*' foo.txt
[a-z]*.*[AHG].*
```

Answer (score 6):

Use [`fgrep`](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_fgrep.htm)
or [`grep -F`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/fgrep) instead if you want to search for literals, not regular expressions.

If you'd merely like to turn off the special meaning of one of the regex characters with `grep`, simply escape it with the backslash, taking note that if you're typing this at a command line, you may need to "escape the escapes" because your shell may strip out one layer of them before passing them to the child.

Comment: what if I want to mix and match, like search for a line of periods using .*?

Comment: @MYV Use single quotes with `bash` or `tcsh`.  Type it as `grep '^\.\.*$'`. This looks for a match starting at the beginning of the line (that's the `^`), followed by one or more periods (`\.` matches the first one, `\.*` matches 0 or more), stretching to the end of the line (`$`).

Answer (score 5):

`grep -F` will not expand regexes. man grep:

> -F, --fixed-strings
>                 Interpret PATTERN as a list of fixed strings, separated by newlines, any of which is to be matched.

Please notice `F` and not `f`!

Comment: What if I want to mix and match